# JavaScript Array sum with condition

Tags: javascript

My task is: Write a code that:

1. Reads values with Window.prompt() to an Array.
2. Finishes 1. as soon as the user inputs an empty string, NaN or presses "Cancel".
3. Prints the sum of all array values.
   My approach:

```
"use strict";
alert("Task 5");
var n = 0;
var arr = new Array();
while(!prompt("Enter a number") === ""
&& !isNaN(prompt("Enter a number"))
&& !prompt("Enter a number") === null){
    n = Number(prompt("Enter a number"));
    arr.push(n);
    sum += n;
}
console.log(sum);
```

I am sorry for being annoying with my hometask, but my experience isn't good yet. Thank You.

Comment: you prompt for a number 4 times, basically disregarding the first 3 as far as the homework assignment is concerned

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: you `prompt` 4 times ... why? also `!prompt("Enter a number") === ""` makes no sense, since `!prompt("Enter a Number")` will never `=== ""` - similarly for the 3rd prompt testing if `!prompt("Enter a number") === null`

Comment: also, `sum` isn't initialized

Comment: Do you mean the === operator must be == there, I must save the prompt to a variable before the loop, do iterative prompts only if the outer suits the conditions?

Comment: NO, I mean `!prompt("Enter a number") === ""` should be `prompt("Enter a number") !== ""` - though, the first 3 `prompt` are MEANINGLESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every loop, you prompt 4 times, and only the last time the value is considered (but it's not validated!! since you validate each response individually in the first three prompts)

Also, you forgot to initialise `sum` so the code would fail there

Here's one way to do what you want

```js
"use strict";
var n = 0;
var arr = new Array();
var sum = 0;
while(true){
    n = prompt("Enter a number");
    if (n === "" || isNaN(n) || n === null) {
        break;
    }
    n = Number(n);
    arr.push(n);
    sum += n;
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Jaromanda X (:.